# How to refactor complex method in Rails model with Rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, refactoring

I have the following complex method. I'm trying to find and implement possible improvements. Right now I moved last if statement to `Access` class.

```
def add_access(access)
   if access.instance_of?(Access)
     up = UserAccess.find(:first, :conditions => ['user_id = ? AND access_id = ?', self.id, access.id])
     if !up && company
       users = company.users.map{|u| u.id unless u.blank?}.compact
       num_p = UserAccess.count(:conditions => ['user_id IN (?) AND access_id = ?', users, access.id])
       if num_p < access.limit
         UserAccess.create(:user => self, :access => access)
       else
         return "You have exceeded the maximum number of alotted permissions"
       end
     end
   end
 end
```

I would like to add also specs before refactoring. I added first one. How should looks like others?

```
  describe "#add_permission" do
    before do
      @permission = create(:permission)
      @user = create(:user)
    end

    it "allow create UserPermission" do
      expect {
        @user.add_permission(@permission)
      }.to change {
        UserPermission.count
      }.by(1)
    end
  end
```

Comment: It's possible that this method is complex because your model relationships are complex. What are these models and why/how do they interact?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I would do it.

Make the check on the Access more like an initial assertion, and raise an error if that happens.

Make a new method to check for an existing user access - that seems reusable, and more readable.

Then, the company limit is more like a validation to me, move this to the UserAccess class as a custom validation.

```
class User

  has_many :accesses, :class_name=>'UserAccess'

  def add_access(access)
    raise "Can only add a Access: #{access.inspect}" unless access.instance_of?(Access)

    if has_access?(access)
      logger.debug("User #{self.inspect} already has the access #{access}")
      return false
    end

    accesses.create(:access => access)
  end

  def has_access?(access)
    accesses.find(:first, :conditions => {:access_id=> access.id})
  end

end

class UserAccess

  validate :below_company_limit

  def below_company_limit
    return true unless company
    company_user_ids = company.users.map{|u| u.id unless u.blank?}.compact
    access_count = UserAccess.count(:conditions => ['user_id IN (?) AND access_id = ?', company_user_ids, access.id])
    access_count < access.limit
  end

end
```

Comment: I am assuming there is an association to UserAccess, or that you can add one.

Comment: I would also suggest renaming `num_p` to `number_of_permissions` and `users` to `company_users_ids`. And definitely make sure you are testing your code, it makes refactorings like this an incredibly joyful experience!

Comment: good point - I left that alone so it was clearer where the code came from, but you are right. edited to reflect your changes.

Comment: How should example spec for that method looks like? Could you give me some hints?

Answer (score 2):

Do you have unit and or integration tests for this class?
I would write some first before refactoring.

Assuming you have tests, the first goal might be shortening the length of this method.

Here are some improvements to make:

1. Move the `UserAccess.find` call to the `UserAccess` model and make it a named scope.
2. Likewise, move the `count` method as well.

Retest after each change and keep extracting until it's clean.   Everyone has a different opinion of clean, but you know it when you see it.

Comment: +1 for encouraging tests! Test, then refactor, then test. Rinse and repeat.

Answer (score 1):

Other thought, not related to moving the code but still cleaner :

```
users = company.users.map{|u| u.id unless u.blank?}.compact
num_p = UserAccess.count(:conditions => ['user_id IN (?) AND access_id = ?', users, access.id])
```

Can become :

```
num_p = UserAccess.where(user_id: company.users, access_id: access.id).count
```